# Unable to connect to RDP from Android using AzureAD credentials

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, android

I'm trying to use the Android RDP client to connect to a machine with AzureAD credentials however it constantly rejects what I send. Does anyone know of any special options I need to do to make this work?

I've tried the following:

azuread\user@emailaddress.com
azuread\user (retrieved from whoami)
user@emailaddress.com

Any ideas? It works from Windows to Windows, just not Android to Windows.

ta,
Justin